# How to put nested if else in ngstyle in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to apply dynamic height to my table.
so for that i have written one function which is giving me available height on screen. and after that i am using that height for my table.
suppose i am getting availHeight from function as 440 px .
i have four table a, b, c, d and i can expand and collapse table
now i want to apply-

```
ngStyle=> if expanded== true then height should be == availHeight for all four tables
and if expanded== false and table=='a' then height should be availHeight-150 else (for b,c,d)
height should be availHeight-30
```

i have tried to write this like -

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'height.px': expanded  ? availHeight : table === 'a' ?
                    (availHeight -150, 'width': 100 + '%') : (availHeight - 30, 'width': 100 + '%')}">
```

But i am getting error in this.

Please help how can i write this in ternary conditions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline style attribute separately for both

like this:

```html
[style.height.px]="expanded ? availHeight : table === 'a' ?  availHeight-150 : availHeight-30"
[style.width.%]="expanded ? 100 : 'initial'"
```

if expanded is false 'initial' width is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
[ngStyle]="{
    'height': expanded ? availHeight
            : !expanded && table=='a'? availHeight - 30
            : defaultVal, //some default val
     'width': expanded ? '100%'
            : !expanded && table=='a'?  (100-10)+'%'
            : defaultVal, //some default val
  }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a much easier time doing this sort of logic in your component, and exposing the resulting style to the html template as a variable.

It's pretty much never a good idea to have logic like this directly in the template.